# Create button with different Find range

Tags: vba, excel

Using this to create a button:-

```
Sub CreateButton4()
Dim i&
With ActiveSheet
    i = .Shapes.Count
    With .Buttons.Add(199.5, 20 + 46 * i, 81, 36)
        .Name = "New Button" & Format(i, "00")
        .OnAction = "MoveValue"
        .Characters.Text = "Submit " & Format(i, "00")
    End With
End With
```

That runs the MoveValue() sub:-

```
Sub MoveValue()
With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(8).Find(Range("C3").Value, , , 1).Offset(0, 1)
    .Value = .Value + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value
End With
```

The problem is I want MoveValue() to relate to the cells adjacent to it as I have another sub which submits data to the adjacent cells when the button is created (at the moment I've only written it to work for the first button). Not sure if I'm going about this completely the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

[Image Spreadsheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6rVs.png)
[image: Image Spreadsheet1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property TopLeftCell as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197363(v=office.11).aspx). But you have to change your layout like this, so the top left cell of your button is in the same row as the information you want.

[image]

```
    Sub CreateButton4()
      Dim i&
      With ActiveSheet
        i = .Shapes.Count
          With .Buttons.Add(199.5, 35 + 46 * i, 81, 36)
            .Name = "New Button" & Format(i, "00")
            .OnAction = "MoveValue"
            .Characters.Text = "Submit " & Format(i, "00")
         End With
      End With
  End Sub



  Sub MoveValue()

        Dim tlcRow As Integer

        tlcRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row

        With Plan1
            .Range("H3:H8").Find(.Range("C" & tlcRow).Value).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Range("D" & tlcRow).Value
        End With

    End Sub
```